# Creating default object from empty value error in old WP plugin bp extra signup

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a line that is throwing the `Creating default object from empty value` error in the now 2 years defunct `bp-extra-signup` plugin for buddypress.

The function that the line lives in is this one:

```
/**
 * Declare our options
 * @since 1.0
 */

function globals()
{
    if( $options = get_option( 'bpxs_options' ) )
    {
        foreach( $options as $key => $var )
            $this->options->{$key} = $var;
    }
}
```

and the line that is throwing the error is:

```
$this->options->{$key} = $var;
```

Like so many others I have read through as many duplicate questions regarding this strict error as possible and can't work out how to handle it in my specific instance to fix it.

I've mostly seen issues regarding a NULL or empty variable where it is obvious or where the variable needs to be declared, but this one is over my head. Why is that line throwing an error?

Comment: Have you made sure `$options` actually has data?

Comment: This is an old wordpress plugin and I have set options in its options page, and it displays those set options on the page, so, I concluded that it does have options stored in the database ... this is an example of what is happening in respect to WP plugin authors getting their options out of the database ... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91764/save-and-retrieve-custom-plugin-options-value ... I've just never seen it done the way this plugin is doing it and have no idea how to fix~

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can do an ini_set, if this site is already launched.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
error_reporting(0);
```

You can also try to add this:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
```

Then you can also try checking the object:

```
if( $this->options != null ) {
  $this->options->$key = $var;
}
```

Comment: I tried to add the code for checking the object but it just made the plugin silently fail for some reason that is also over my head ... I'm not interested in just silencing the error, so, I'm only looking to actually fix this plugin properly ...

Still hoping for a solution~

Comment: Okay, I think you should try using the "isset" function to check if your variable or object is set correctly